# How to capture photo automatically using Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am building an app, where when I open the camera through app, it should automatically(without clicking button on phone) capture the photo. Is it possible to achieve using Ionic Cordova?

Answer (score -1):

1 - Well first try to add code to the question

2 - You can trigger the method to take picture in `iondidLoad()` or `iondidEnter()` after platform is ready